# Bash Script that downloads file from FTP only if it hasn't downloaded it previously

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ftp, sftp

I currently have a bash script that downloads files from an FTP Site. I would like to modify the script to keep a manifest of every file it downloads and only download any new files that are not in the manifest. Is there a way to do this in bash or am I pushing the limitations of what bash can actually do?

Comment: It depends on the speed you're looking for and on the number of concerned files. I wrote something like that checks a few thousands file every minutes. It keeps listings and checks received size against listed sizes. Works quite well, using lftp. But you could just use rsync in simple cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, rsync can't be an option here as the files on the local will be moved to an archive but the files on the remote are moved occasionally.  I'm only looking at doing this 2-3 times a day and the number of files could be around 1-10 (and 10 is a lot).  I'm open for lftp if you could assist.  Thank you!

Comment: Uh. code is about 500 lines long and has /private/ data in it but basically it uses lftp for a 'ls' command, records its output and the compare (via sort and two 'while' interleaved bash loops ) to what it gave at previous call, building the next lftp 'get' script file.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to go grab the list of files that you might want to download, compare that to your manifest, then download the ones not in the manifest.  Something like this should work:

```
ftp username@hostname <<EOF
ls * filelist.txt
EOF
cat filelist.txt | awk '{print $9}' | tail -n +3 > filenames.txt
while IFS= read -r file
  do
    if [[ ! $(grep "$file" manifest.txt) ]]; then
       echo "$file is not in manifest"
    fi
  done < "filenames.txt"
```

Of course, you'll need to change `filelist.txt` and `filenames.txt` to include an appropriate path.  Also, change the `echo` command to add the filename to another file or variable that you'll use to do the actual download.

Here's an explanation of what's going on:

The first three lines use `ftp` to grab a list of files (You'll want to change the `*` to point to the correct directory.)

The `cat` line parses the output of the ftp `ls` command to grab just the filename part and put it into another file.

Then the while loop goes through the list of files and uses grep to see if the filename exists in the manifest file.  If it doesn't, you can then download it and add it to the manifest.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! What would be the best way of updating the Manifest with the newly downloaded filenames?  Thx!

Comment: Depending on what info you want to store in the manifest, you could do something like: `echo "$file - $(date)" >> manifest.txt` -- the double-greater-thans ("`>>`") mean to append the output to the file and the `$(date)` grabs the output of the date command (which looks like this: `Tue Apr 18 10:34:52 PDT 2017`).