# compare filenames in between directory and mapping file

Tags: shell

In a directory i have few files as:

```
a.txt
c.txt
c.txt
z.txt
```

and in different directory i have a file name called map_file with data like:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
e.txt
f.txt
```

I want to compare(only filenames not content of filenames) files exits in directory with the filenames that are in map_file.and if new file is found in directory(does not exits in map_file)then copy and rename file to some other directory.

Comment: If constrained to shell, you could `grep` for each first-list filename in your map file and use that result to determine whether or not to copy/rename.

Comment: grep of each file doesn't seems to be good idea

Answer (score 0):

If constrained to shell, you could grep for each first-list filename in your map file and use that result to determine whether or not to copy/rename. Something like this:

```
cd dir_a
for f in *; do
    if ! grep -qE '^'"$f"'$' /path/map_file; then
         cp "$f" /dir_b/new_name
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer to [this question that is very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473762/bash-script-that-downloads-file-from-ftp-only-if-it-hasnt-downloaded-it-previou/43478348#43478348).

In short, you could loop on the files and find them in your file:

```
for file in *.txt
  do
    if [[ ! $(grep "$file" /path/to/map_file) ]]; then
       echo "$file is not in map_file -- copy/rename somewhere else."
    fi
  done
```

That should do it for you.

Let me know if you have any questions.